# returning string in C function

Tags: c, string, char

I was trying to solve **CountAndSay** problem at one of the online coding site but I am not able to get why my program is printing `NULL`. I am sure I am doing some conceptual mistake but not getting it.

Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* countAndSay(int A) {
    int i,j,k,f,count;
    char a;

    char *c = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    char *temp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    c[0] = 1;c[1] = '\0';
    for(k=2; k<=A; k++)
    {
        for(i=0, j=0; i<strlen(c); i++)
        {    
            a = c[i];
            count = 1;
            i++;

            while(c[i] != '\0')
            {
                if(c[i]==a)
                {
                    count++;
                    i++;
                }
                else if(c[i] != a)
                {
                    i--;
                break;
                }
                else
                {
                break;
                }
            }
            temp[j] = count;
            temp[j+1] = a;
            j += 2;
        }
        *(temp+j) = '\0';
        if(k<A)
        {
        for(j=0; j<strlen(temp); j++)
        {
                c[j] = temp[j];
        }
        c[j] = '\0';
        }    
    }
    return temp;
}

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    char *c = countAndSay(8);
    printf("%s\n",c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for(i=0, j=0; i<strlen(c); i++)` invokes undefined behavior for accessing uninitialized objects (created by `malloc()`).

Comment: @EOF I don't think that causes any problem because I have initialized c before

Comment: No, you have initialized *part of* the array `c` points to the first element of, and you have initialized that part to a non-zero value.

Comment: In `strlen(c);` the array `c` is not a string, and so does not have a valid length. Your initialisation was to write a `1` to `c[0]` and that's all. The content of the rest of the allocated memory is unknown.

Comment: Yes you have initialized `c[0]` to `1`, which makes no sense. But that's all you have initiialized, the rest of the memory is still uninitialized and therefore has an *indeterminate* contents.

Comment: `strlen` works by searching for the first `\0` in the string. You `malloc` space for `c`, set the first `char` to 1 (why?), then immediately loop over its length, which is indeterminate. That could return 5 or 5000, there's no way to tell. That may not be the only problem here but it's the first problem.

Comment: How about a *zero*? That's what `'\0'` is. Or be explicit and do `c[0] = '\0'`

Comment: You'll need to create a valid `nul` terminated string in the memory you were allocated. `malloc` does not initialise the memory it gives you.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have updated the code even now it's not working

Comment: By "not working" do you mean it is still printing `NULL`?

Comment: 1) `(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);` Don't cast `malloc` in `C`. If your compiler says that you have to, then you are using a `C++` compiler. 2) `sizeof((char) * 100)` is the same as `sizeof(100)`

Comment: It doesnt print NULL, i compiled and ran it. It returns '\0'.

Comment: Has `free` become too old fashion?

Comment: Here, your program gives some compiler warnings, and prints 10 smiley faces and hearts. These are non-ASCII low-valued characters shown by my console. You have initialised `c` to a string that contained `1` which I think is one of those smiley things. Certainly it is not the character `'1'`. There is no input so I don't understand the "count and say" part.

Comment: Suggest declaring `c` as `char c[100] = { 1, '\0' };`.  There's no need for dynamic allocation here (unlike for `temp`), as the needed size is fixed, and the array does not need to outlive the function call.  That also allows initializing it in the declaration, which is a bit tidier.

Comment: As far as I can see this code never adds anything except `'\0'` to the arrays.

Comment: Your `if` / `else if` / `else` construct is suspicious: if the first condition is not met then the second one will be met; the final `else` is never reached.

Comment: input? expected output? actual output?

Comment: @4386427 CountAndSay: A program that receives a number : for example: 312 and outputs its verbal context. 312 one 3's one 1's, one 2's -> 131112. Another example is 4111221 -> one 4's three 1's two 2's and one 1' -> 14312211

Comment: Your revised code still has undefined behavior around `strlen()`.  Although you now set a terminator at index 1, that terminator will be overwritten as your function runs, without introducing a new one, and `strlen()` called again afterward.  That would be solved by declaring the array as I earlier suggested (with the initializer), provided that you never overrun the array bound.

Comment: You evidently have some confusion between the distinct values `1` and `'1'`, *etc*..  The `char` values representing decimal digit characters are of the latter form -- those are what you seem to want in your output string.  Their numeric values are (normally) different from those of the digits they represent.  You can convert by adding or subtracting `'0'` (`'1' == '0' + 1`).

Comment: After making the appropriate ASCII adjustment, just at the point of output, I get the output `1113213211`. I did this with `int i = 0; while(c[i]) { printf("%c", c[i++] + '0'); }`. But it remains uncertain how you will cope with `0` when you mean it to be a digit and not a `nul `terminator..

Comment: Adding:     char* p = temp - 1;
    while (*(++p) != '\0')
    {
        *p += '0';
    }
at the end of the func worked for me, i guess you kept every value as a number and not as an ascii character...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is not that bad, the main errors are the mix-up of numerical digits and characters as shown in the comments.

Also: if you use dynamic memory, than use dynamic memory. If you only want to use a fixed *small* amount you should use the stack instead, e.g.: `c[100]`, but that came up in the comments, too. You also need only one piece of memory. Here is a working example based on your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
// ALL CHECKS OMMITTED!
char *countAndSay(int A)
{
  int k, count, j;
  // "i" gets compared against the output of
  // strlen() which is of type size_t
  size_t i;
  char a;

  // Seed needs two bytes of memory 
  char *c = malloc(2);
  // Another pointer, pointing to the same memory later.
  // Set to NULL to avoid an extra malloc()
  char *temp = NULL;
  // a temporary pointer needed for realloc()-ing
  char *cp;
  // fill c with seed
  c[0] = '1';
  c[1] = '\0';
  if (A == 1) {
    return c;
  }
  // assuming 1-based input, that is: the first 
  // entry of the sequence is numbered 1 (one)
  for (k = 2; k <= A; k++) {
    // Memory needed is twice the size of
    // the former entry at most.
    // (Averages to Conway's constant but that
    // number is not usable here, it is only a limit)
    cp = realloc(temp, strlen(c) * 2 + 1);
    temp = cp;
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < strlen(c); i++) {
      //printf("A i = %zu, j = %zu\n",i,j);
      a = c[i];
      count = 1;
      i++;
      while (c[i] != '\0') {
        if (c[i] == a) {
          count++;
          i++;
        } else {
          i--;
          break;
        }
      }
      temp[j++] = count + '0';
      temp[j++] = a;
      //printf("B i = %zu, j = %zu\n",i,j-1)
      //printf("B i = %zu, j = %zu\n",i,j);
    }
    temp[j] = '\0';
    if (k < A) {
      // Just point "c" to the new sequence in "temp".
      // Why does this work and temp doesn't overwrite c later?
      // Or does it *not* always work and fails at one point?
      // A mystery! Try to find it out! Some hints in the code.
      c = temp;
      temp = NULL;
    }
    // intermediate results:
    //printf("%s\n\n",c);
  }
  return temp;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  // your code goes here
  char *c = countAndSay(atoi(argv[1]));
  printf("%s\n", c);
  free(c);
  return 0;
}
```

To get a way to check for sequences not in the list over at [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A005150), I rummaged around in my attic and found this little "gem":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

char *conway(char *s)
{
  char *seq;
  char c;
  size_t len, count, i = 0;

  len = strlen(s);
  /*
   * Worst case is twice as large as the input, e.g.:
   * 1 -> 11
   * 21 -> 1211
   */
  seq = malloc(len * 2 + 1);
  if (seq == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }
  while (len) {
    // counter for occurrences of ...
    count = 0;
    // ... this character
    c = s[0];
    // as long as the string "s" 
    while (*s != '\0' && *s == c) {
      // move pointer to next character
      s++;
      // increment counter
      count++;
      // decrement the length of the string
      len--;
    }
    // to keep it simple, fail if c > 9
    // but that cannot happen with a seed of 1
    // which is used here.
    // For other seeds it might be necessary to
    // use a map with the higher digits as characters.
    // If it is not possible to fit it into a
    // character, the approach with a C-string is
    // obviously not reasonable anymore.
    if (count > 9) {
      free(seq);
      return NULL;
    }
    // append counter as a character
    seq[i++] = (char) (count + '0');
    // append character "c" from above
    seq[i++] = c;
  }
  // return a proper C-string
  seq[i] = '\0';
  return seq;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  long i, n;
  char *seq0, *seq1;

  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s n>0\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  // reset errno, just in case
  errno = 0;
  // get amount from commandline
  n = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0);
  if ((errno == ERANGE && (n == LONG_MAX || n == LONG_MIN))
      || (errno != 0 && n == 0)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "strtol failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  if (n <= 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s n>0\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  // allocate space for seed value "1" plus '\0'
  // If the seed is changed the limit in the conway() function
  // above might need a change.
  seq0 = malloc(2);
  if (seq0 == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed to allocate a measly 2 bytes!?\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  // put the initial value into the freshly allocated memory 
  strcpy(seq0, "1");
  // print it, nicely formatted
  /*
   * putc('1', stdout);
   * if (n == 1) {
   * putc('\n', stdout);
   * free(seq0);
   * exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   * } else {
   * printf(", ");
   * }
   */
  if (n == 1) {
    puts("1");
    free(seq0);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  }
  // adjust count
  n--;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // compute conway sequence as a recursion
    seq1 = conway(seq0);
    if (seq1 == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "conway() failed, probably because malloc() failed\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // make room
    free(seq0);
    seq0 = NULL;
    // print sequence, comma separated
    // printf("%s%s", seq1, (i < n - 1) ? "," : "\n");
    // or print sequence and length of sequence, line separated
    // printf("%zu: %s%s", strlen(seq1), seq1, (i < n-1) ? "\n\n" : "\n");
    // print the endresult only
    if (i == n - 1) {
      printf("%s\n", seq1);
    }
    // reuse seq0
    seq0 = seq1;
    // not necessary but deemed good style by some
    // although frowned upon by others
    seq1 = NULL;
  }
  // free the last memory
  free(seq0);
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```